# resolve_scale(y='independent'), but how can we align two y axes 0 at the same level

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I'm using `resolve_scale(y='independent')`, but how can we align two y-axes `0` at the same level?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions here, please post your code and data so that we can see what you have tried and reproduce it on our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with "align" here. Your axis have different values so if you align the max and min value the data range will be compressed for the right-most axis in your picture. If you just want them both to start from 0, you can set it with `alt.Y('new_deaths', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 1600]))`.

However, I would look into your data to figure out why you have negative deaths on the blue line, seems like something is wrong. Also consider making this figure in two different charts, that could be clearer than having two y-axes in the same chart.

Comment: Thank you. Joe. I did set domain=[0, 1600], those negative part will go beyond the chart frame.  I also checked in the raw data, I think there are some issues in the data, as you see there are negative new death number which is not correct. Also agree this viz with two y axis independent may not be the best solution